# Lost code in Rstudio- r script is blank after computer crash

Tags: r, recovery

I was working in Rstudio and had previously successfully saved a file/Rscript. Sometime later, i was working on the same file and the computer froze, so I turned it off because I hadn't made much progress on the original work. When i reopen R, this file still exists on my computer but when loaded into R, the file is blank except for one line of: "........................................", i.e. a really long elipsis, which was highlighted in red.. Any help on how I can get my original code back?

Comment: happily, Rstudio history recalls everything you've ever typed in console, so if you have any recollection of something you typed in your script, type it in history search and follow to when you were developing your script. You should be able to reconstruct.

Comment: Thank you! this answered my question very well